# How to bind selected/option value to get request function in service.ts and not component.ts (Angular 8)

Tags: html, angular, http, angular8

I need help on how to get selected value and concatenate it to a url inside my "service.ts" and then use the function in which the url is placed in my component.ts. I know how to bind data from component.html to component.ts but what i would like to know is binding to service.ts. See my code below:

**component.html**

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" [(ngModel)]="bindSelect">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Choose item</option>
  <option [value]="mydata.name" *ngFor="let mydata of vList$">
     <td>{{ mydata.id }} - {{ mydata.name }}</td>
  </option>
</select>
```

**service.ts**

```
export class ItenService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

myUrl = 'http://localhost:4045/store/itemList';
valueFromSelect = '';

getData() {
    return this.http.get<itemData[]>('http://localhost:4045/store/itemList/' + this.valueFromSelect);
  }

}
```

**component.ts**

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
vList$ = [];
bindSelect = '';
  constructor(private idataService: IdataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getImpl();
  } 
  getImpl() {
    // impl service.ts function here
  } 
}
```

How do I bind "valueFromSelect" from from .html to service.ts, so that when I select item, the value binds to valueFromSelect = ' ';

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly bind your `.html` to the service instance. This is facilitated by your `component.ts`

So the approach is to bind the **service.ts-component.ts-html** together. See the snippet below.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dugokj)

**.html**

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" [(ngModel)]="valueFromSelect" (change)="onSelect()">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Choose item</option>
  <option [value]="mydata.name" *ngFor="let mydata of vList">
     <td>{{ mydata.id }} - {{ mydata.name }}</td>
  </option>
</select>
```

**.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SampleService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  vList;
  valueFromSelect;

  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // gets from service
    this.vList = this.sampleService.vList;
  }

  onSelect() {
    console.log(this.valueFromSelect);
    // sets to the service
    this.sampleService.valueFromSelect = this.valueFromSelect;
  }
}
```

**.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SampleService {
  vList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob'
  }];
  valueFromSelect;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: This part "this.sampleService.valueFromSelect = this.valueFromSelect" of the .component.ts solves the problem. It was nice that you showed the "(change)" in the .html.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to change the code in component.TS to this.
Call the function getImpl() when the selection from dropdown gets changed.

**component.ts**

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
vList$ = [];
bindSelect = '';
  constructor(private idataService: IdataService,private ItenService: ITenService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getImpl();
  } 
  getImpl() {
    this.ItenService.valueFromSelect = this.bindSelect;
    // impl service.ts function here
      this.ItenService.getData();
  } 
}
```